# Seed job fails to create a MavenJob but no error is reported

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I created a Junit jenkins test case where a in-memory jenkins instance is launched (as we use @Rule jenkinsrule). The code of the test case is available [here](https://github.com/ch007m/jenkins-job-dsl/blob/31efa049a95c333a8dba9b01ff2aa281b3520e34/src/test/java/dev/snowdrop/MavenJobDSLTest.java#L25-L53).
The test case will create a FreeStyleProject (= seed job) which will use as Groovy script DSL a maven.groovy [file](https://github.com/ch007m/jenkins-job-dsl/blob/31efa049a95c333a8dba9b01ff2aa281b3520e34/src/main/resources/mavenJob.groovy)

But when the test case is executed, the following message is reported during the the job build execution. The message reports ghe consequence of the import/parsing of the mavenJob.groovy file as the job expects that a new job will be created.

```
Legacy code started this job.  No cause information is available
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/folders/t2/jwchtqkn5y76hrfrws7dqtqm0000gn/T/j h5344303144116520886/workspace/test0
Processing provided DSL script
ERROR: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/folders/t2/jwchtqkn5y76hrfrws7dqtqm0000gn/T/j h5344303144116520886/jobs/mvn-spring-boot-rest-http/config.xml
Finished: FAILURE
```

And of course no stack trace of the error is stdout or stderr.
How can I investigate the problem and fix it ?

Remark:

If I use the config.xml file and import it in a separate jenkins instance, the job succeeded

config.xml file generated, it looks good (vs same config.xml file created using the UI)

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <canRoam>false</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
    <javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts>
      <scriptText>mavenJob(&apos;mvn-spring-boot-rest-http&apos;) {
    description &apos;A Maven Job compiling the project Spring Boot Rest HTTP Example&apos;

    parameters {
        gitParameter {
            name &apos;SELECTED_TAG&apos;
            description &apos;The Git tag to checkout&apos;
            type &apos;PT_TAG&apos;
            defaultValue &apos;2.3.4-2&apos;
            branch &apos;&apos;
            branchFilter &apos;origin/(.*)&apos;
            quickFilterEnabled false
            selectedValue &apos;DEFAULT&apos;
            sortMode &apos;DESCENDING_SMART&apos;
            tagFilter &apos;*&apos;
            useRepository &apos;.*rest-http-example.git&apos;
            listSize &apos;10&apos;
        }
    }

    scm {
        git {
            remote {
                url &apos;https://github.com/snowdrop/rest-http-example.git&apos;
                // branch(&apos;$SELECTED_TAG&apos;)
                branch(&apos;2.3.4-2&apos;)
            }
        }
    }
    rootPOM &apos;pom.xml&apos;
    goals &apos;clean install&apos;
}</scriptText>
      <usingScriptText>true</usingScriptText>
      <sandbox>false</sandbox>
      <ignoreExisting>false</ignoreExisting>
      <ignoreMissingFiles>false</ignoreMissingFiles>
      <failOnMissingPlugin>false</failOnMissingPlugin>
      <failOnSeedCollision>false</failOnSeedCollision>
      <unstableOnDeprecation>false</unstableOnDeprecation>
      <removedJobAction>IGNORE</removedJobAction>
      <removedViewAction>IGNORE</removedViewAction>
      <removedConfigFilesAction>IGNORE</removedConfigFilesAction>
      <lookupStrategy>JENKINS_ROOT</lookupStrategy>
    </javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts>
  </builders>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

I created a thread discussion here too: https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-users/c/mRSwARFapyA

Charles

Answer (score -1):

The problem was related to many missing dependencies needed to run the test case.
I upgraded the `build.gradle` file and now that works.

https://github.com/ch007m/jenkins-job-dsl/blob/jenkins-2.271/build.gradle#L53-L72

BTW, the error message reported was not correlated at all to the root cause and How to fix the problem. that should be improved within the code ;-)